# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have a wcf web application that is hosting the services on a server. I'm creating the client(api) to read these services.

I have added tracing to my service side using:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="bin\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

The .svclog file does not show any errors, so I'm guessing it has to do with the de-serialization of the objects on the client side. How do I see if this is the case?

Help in ways to trace the issue would be great.

I had to add to the SETters the if null due to an error that the private members were null. Ever since then, I have been getting the http errors.

Example of the DTO:

```
[DataContract]
public class PersonDTO 
{              
    private CUSTOMType<string> givenNameField ;    
    private CUSTOMType<string> middleNameField ;    
    private CUSTOMType<string> familyNameField ;         

    [DataMember]
    public string GivenName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.givenNameField.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.givenNameField == null)
                this.givenNameField = new CUSTOMType<string>(); 
            this.givenNameField.Value = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string MiddleName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.middleNameField.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.middleNameField == null)
                this.middleNameField = new CUSTOMType<string>(); 
            this.middleNameField.Value = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.familyNameField.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.familyNameField == null)
                this.familyNameField = new CUSTOMType<string>(); 
            this.familyNameField.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Originally I had two objects: Business and DTO. The only difference was that the DTO was just straight C# datatypes, where the Business layer has logic and my CUSTOMType. This worked with no problem. Now I saw this as duplication and was trying to combined the two. It might be possible that the binary serialization process just doesn't like my custom types.

The constructor at one point, did have the init of the private members. The service throw errors that the private members were null. That is why I changed to to the SETTERS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both havardhu and bryanmac gave me pieces to find my issue. In the end it was a mapping issue with the ORM AutoMapper.dll that I'm using.

One of the mapping statements was not present.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<>();
```

WCF is not great at giving error message, and I would have hoped that the WCF team would improve on that.

Answer (score 2):

Add similar tracing on the client side, this might shed some light on what's going on.

Do you also have a DataContract defined for your `CUSTOMType<T>`?

Edit; Have you made sure that the private fields are never null when your get properties are called during serialization? If the property is not set, it could cause a null reference exception. Maybe try to instantiate the private fields in your constructor?

Comment: No I don't have a data contract for CUSTOMType<t>? Do I need one even though that is the private members? If so, how much of this object would need to be a datacontract?

Comment: No never mind that, I was a bit quick and didnt notice you only expose strings.

Comment: I'll add in the tracing to the client side tomorrow(am) and see. Still strange that I would only now be getting some kind of error.

Comment: Have you made sure that the private fields are never null when your get properties are called during serialization? If the property is not set, it could cause a null reference exception. Maybe try to instantiate the private fields in your constructor?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to client side tracing, you can also download fiddler.  It runs as a proxy between you and the server and allows you to see exactly what is being sent to and received from the server.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I will try this as well. Cheers.